# Wireless internet not working with Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, kubuntu, 22.04, internet, realtek-wireless

I just installed Kubuntu 22.04 on my new HP laptop and the wireless internet doesn't work at all. I'm a newbie with this sort of thing so I'm not sure how to fix this (besides using USB tethering with my phone as a workaround for the time being).

I used `sudo lshw -C network` to find out the exact wireless adapter it's using:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller  
   product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.  
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.  
   physical id: 0  
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0  
   version: 00  
   width: 64 bits  
   clock: 33MHz  
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list  
   configuration: latency=0  
   resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0500000-c05fffff
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)